# Ubuntu 18.04 openconnect wont update resolv.conf

Tags: networking, dns, vpn, openconnect

As the title says, every time I connect to the VPN using Network Manager (or by console) using openconnect my resolv.conf won't update correctly...

For example, this is how my resolv.conf file look using openconnect

```
search company.com
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Now If I run anyconnect my resolv.conf file looks something like this:

```
domain company.com
nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
nameserver yyy.yy.yyy.yyy
search company.com
```

I don't know if I'm missing any configuration for openconnect... or if this is a bug...